# Prolog error: No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'

Tags: prolog

I have just started with prolog (don't ask me why), and I have written the following simple program:

```
member(X,[X|_Tail]).
member(X,[_Head|Tail]) :-
    member(X,Tail).

list = [bob,carol,ted,alice].
```

when I try the following query

```
member(bob,l)
```

(I am using SWISH prolog, so I don't need to use the question mark),I get the error:

```
No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'
```

I've looked around and not sure what the issue is, nor what this means. Any spots?

Comment: Say `mylist([bob,carol,ted,alice]).` instead and query `?- mylist(L), member(bob,L).`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error:

> `No permission to modify static procedure '(=)/2'`

because this line in your source code:

```
list = [bob,carol,ted,alice].
```

[tries to] define the predicate `=/2`. It is exactly identical to

```
'='( list , [bob, carol, ted, alice] ) .
```

Which, if compiled, would override the unification operator `=/2` with a version that would always fail (because the atom `list` cannot unify with  the list `[bob, carol, ted, alice]`.

At the prolog prompt, however, one could query `list = [bob, carol, ted, alice].` and have it fail. Or more likely query `List  = [bob, carol, ted, alice].` and have it succeed and report the new value of `List`.

If you want to specify a goal to run at startup, then something like this:

```
start_my_program :- writeln(hello) .

:- start_my_program .
```

would do you, specifying the initial goal to be evaluated.